# Can not enable indexing in XCode 6.1

Tags: xcode

It was a while when I disabled indexing in XCode simply writing

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

Now I am quite disappointed with that the code completion doesn't work, but no method to enable indexing back again works. I observed that XCode restores the com.apple.dt.XCode.plist file at every launch, so it doesn't matter whether I include IDEIndexEnable or IDEIndexDisable keys to the plist — they are simply ignored.

The things I've tried are:

- overwrite IDEIndexDisable by 0
- delete IDEIndexDisable, then write IDEIndexEnable 1
- delete IDEIndexDisable, then write IDEIndexDisable 0
- many other combinations with keys and even values (YES/NO, TRUE/FALSE, 0/1)
- clear all cached XCode files in ~Library/Preferences/ and other folders
- restart, reboot, reinstall XCode

Basically, I expect something strange with XCode which uses the same plist again and again (and restores it from somewhere). I'm quite desperate asking there for help and appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as yours. I finally figured it out:

First, execute `defaults delete com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable`.
Then, reboot your mac.

After rebooted, `Xcode` start index again!

Comment: I had the same problem - it looks like the setting is being cached. Instead of rebooting, you can also quit cfprefsd (from "Activity Monitor").